# SQL select column name where value is greater than zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help to write SQL query to make Table B from Table A ?

[image: Table A to Table B SQL query]

Comment: Your table design has a problem, and each month's sales should not be getting its own column, but rather its own _record_ within a single column for all sales.

Comment: stackoverlfow is not a code writing service. You are expected to show your attempt

Comment: Provide sample data, instead of putting image

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using CROSS APPLY .

```sql
DECLARE @table table(country varchar(20), city varchar(20), SalesJan20 decimal(2,1), salesFeb20  decimal(2,1), SalesMar20  decimal(2,1), SalesApril20  decimal(2,1))

insert into @table values('Bangladesh','dhaka',0, 1.5,0,1), ('Bangladesh','comilla',2.5,0, 1.6,1);

;WITH CTE_CountryCity AS
(
SELECT country, city, min(case when monthval > 0 then monthnum end) as min_Month,  max(case when monthval > 0 then monthnum end) as max_month  
FROM @table
cross apply
(values
(1,'SalesJan20',SalesJan20),(2,'salesFeb20',salesFeb20),(3,'SalesMar20',SalesMar20),(4,'SalesApril20',SalesApril20)
)as c(Monthnum,MonthNm,Monthval)
group by country, city
)
select country, city, min_Month as SalesStartMonth, max_month as SalesEndMonth, (max_month - min_Month) as RangeMonth
from CTE_CountryCity
```

| country | city | SalesStartMonth | SalesEndMonth | RangeMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bangladesh | comilla | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| Bangladesh | dhaka | 2 | 4 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross apply`.  I would be inclined to do this as:

```
select a.country, a.city,
       choose(min_n, 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr') as sales_start_month,
       choose(max_n, 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr') as sales_end_month,
       v.range_month
from a cross apply
     (select min(n) as min_n, max(n) as max_n,
             max(n) - min(n) as range_month
      from (values (1, SalesJan20), (2, SalesFeb20), (3, SalesMar20), (4, SalesApr20)
           ) v(n, val)
      where val is not null
     ) v;
```

The key idea here is doing the aggregation in the subquery used for the `cross apply`.  Doing the aggregation "locally" rather than over the entire table should be a big win from a performance perspective.